# How to bypass the WSL step when setting up a vscode devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I am working on a Windows 10 machine but connecting to a Linux server (Ubuntu 22.04) over SSH using vscode to develop. On the Linux server, I am developing a devcontainer. I have been running into an issue that has been slowing down my progress whenever I build my devcontainer (by selecting Dev Containers: Rebuild Container or Reopen in Container).

Looking at the log when the devcontainer is opening, I see one of the first steps is to try to connect to WSL. I assume this is happening because even though I am developing on a Linux server, I am SSHing from a Windows machine that is running vscode. The problem is that this step takes 4 minutes every time I build. And I don't want to use WSL at all so I am waiting 4 minutes for that step to fail before the rest of my devcontainer will build anytime I make a change where I need to rebuild the devcontainer.

[image]

Are there any settings that can be used to skip that step or force it to fail quickly so development can be sped up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12548#issue-1135126079).
I ran into a similar issue in the past where WSL was working fine but it stopped working after I installed Docker. When I would try to open my Ubuntu distribution from WSL it would just hang and if I tried to open Docker Desktop it would also hang but never open.
From the log you posted, it reminds me of the issue I had with Docker and WSL interacting. The lines that say `Could not connect to WSL; command failed: wsl -l -v` suggest that WSL is just hanging until vscode deems it acceptable to error out and then moves on.

The link details the following steps:

- Follow the official steps on how to install WSL 2 at
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
- Open PowerShell and run command:

  - wsl --update
- Uninstall Docker.
- Delete temporary data:

  - C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
  - C:\Users\ProgramData\Docker
  - C:\Users\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
- Reinstall Docker, ensure wsl box is ticked during install.
- Restart computer.
- Run Docker as administrator.
- Run PowerShell as administrator.
- Run the following command:

  - & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon

  If this doesn't work, you may need to run the above command one or two more times.

Comment: Thank you it looked like this solved my issue! I did check and I was unable to get WSL or Docker Desktop working (ie they would both just hang if I tried to load either). I was unable to delete all the temporary data and did have to restart Docker Desktop after running the last command, but my issue is still resolved and my devcontainer opens with no delays

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the docker error is slowing the process.
When I search for it I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112701/vs-code-fails-to-run-a-container-through-dev-containers). I also think this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3525) may help you.

Basically the stack overflow discussion was solved by using the command `"runArgs": ["--gpus", "all"]` instead of `"runArgs": ["--gpus all"]`. The flag and the argument needs to be their own strings.